# Exception thrown from sharpdx assembly when calling, why?

Tags: c#, sharpdx, direct3d9

I am trying to load volume from file of type raw with given dimensions which are specified higher in code( mWidth, mHeight, mDepth). I want to use `Volume.FromFileInMemory` method. This is piece of the code which should do the loading.

```
Volume volume = new Volume(IntPtr.Zero);
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[mWidth * mHeight * mDepth];
int size = sizeof(byte);
reader.Read(buffer, 0, size * buffer.Length);
Volume.FromFileInMemory(volume,buffer,Filter.None,0);
reader.Close();
```

However when I execute the code I get an weird exception which I don't really understand.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.dll
Additional information: HRESULT: [0x8876086C], Module: [SharpDX.Direct3D9], ApiCode: [D3DERR_INVALIDCALL/InvalidCall], Message: Unknown
```

I read the [documentaion](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-direct3d9-volume-fromfileinmemory-3) for the `FileInMemory` method and googled for a while but I really can't solve this issue.